# jQuery & IE7+ unexpected behaviour with cached $objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I have just noticed an issue that appears to be affecting all versions of IE (tested 7-10) but not Chrome or FF (Windows 7). The issue occurs when I cache a jquery object and then remove its original target.

The code below is essentially rearranging some images in divs in such a way that the selected image comes first, but I am not using a holder div so it is all being done in situ. I would rather not complicate matters by resorting to converting the html to a string, I suspect this may be a well known issue that I just don't know the search terms for so if that is the case please enlighten me!

```
$lightbox_gallery = $('.gallery-lightbox .lightbox-gallery');
$image            = $lightbox_gallery.find('img[data-id=' + image.id + ']').parent();
$image_after      = $image.nextAll();
$image_before     = $lightbox_gallery.find('> div:first').nextUntil($image);

console.log($image.html()); //returns a string
$lightbox_gallery.html('');
console.log($image.html()); //returns ''

// this works fine in almost anything but IE. Maybe also safari on mac?
$lightbox_gallery.append($image).append($image_after).append($image_before);
```

**Edit:** Solved it using the clone function http://jsfiddle.net/27DKZ/4/

Comment: Managed to replicate the problem I think, http://jsfiddle.net/27DKZ/ runs differently in Chrome and IE

Answer (score 0):

What does your HTML look like? I've never seen a problem like this.. Keep in mind that IE cannot handle the console.log() function..

Comment: Okay try this in Chrome and then in IE, I think any version will do it. http://jsfiddle.net/27DKZ/